# How to use C++20 <format> in CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20, fmt, stdformat

I want to use the `<format>` header available in C++20.

I am using the most up-to-date release of CMake.

My CMakeFiles looks like

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++20")
```

I am using Clang 9 as my compiler.

However, I am getting the following error when including `<format>`:

```
fatal error: 'format' file not found
#include <format>
```

I have also used the flag `-std=c++2a`, with no effect.
How can I use C++20 `<format>`?

Comment: Good news! MSVC now supports text formatting.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) page ([archive](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/compiler_support&oldid=161627)) on cppreference, C++20 `<format>` functionalities are fully supported by

- GCC libstdc++ 13;
- MSVC STL 19.29 (Visual Studio 2019 16.10); and
- Clang libc++ 17.<sup>*</sup>

You will be able to use `#include <format>` normally after upgrading to these versions.

If upgrading is not an option for one reason or another, you can still use the [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library, which was the basis for the standardization of the C++20 `<format>` library.  There are [minimal differences](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#compatibility-with-c-20-std-format) between C++20 `<format>` and the {fmt} library.

---

<sup>*</sup> Experimental support is available since Clang libc++ 14 through the `-fexperimental-library` compiler flag.

Comment: I wonder why this is the case. Is it that hard to implement `<format>`? More complex parts like "concepts" seem to be already supported by most compilers.

Comment: @Ayxan Concepts started as a TS; many compilers have worked on it several years ago. `<format>`, however, is mostly just the fmt library standardized.

Comment: I came accross this post, searching for a different c++20 feature being supported and followed your link. The table changed a little, but `Text formatting` is still all red.
@Tak Makoni: in case you use MSVC, here is a list of supported features per MSVC version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: Text formatting is now supported by GCC, Clang (partially), and MSVC. So this answer is outdated.